# cursor error on camera picture uri

Tags: android, uri, android-camera-intent, android-cursor

I'm implementing an option to pick an image from either the gallery or from the camera. I then check the orientation of the image and rotate it if necessary (e.g. Samsung phones when taking portrait pictures).
It works fine on gallery pictures, but **I get an error on camera picture when calling "cursor.getInt(0)"**. Obviously there is something wrong with my uri and cursor handling, but I don't know what it is.

This is how I take picture:

```
mCameraFileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), com.example.android.fileprovider", cameraPhotoFile);

Intent pickImageFromCamera = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
pickImageFromCamera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCameraFileUri);
```

My getOrientation method (which works only on gallery pictures):

```
public static int getOrientation(Context context, Uri selectedImage) {
        int orientation = -1;
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                new String[]{MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION}, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null || cursor.getCount() != 1)
            return orientation;

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        orientation = cursor.getInt(0);
        cursor.close();
        return orientation;
    }
```

An example for selectedImage uri when picking from gallery:  `content://com.miui.gallery.open/raw/%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FDCIM%2FCamera%2FIMG_20180805_100104.jpg`

When taking a picture using the camera, I just use the uri from the intent, so selectedImage is:

```
content://com.example.android.fileprovider/my_images/cameraPicture.jpg
```

When using for uri from the file path, I just get null cursor:

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/apps.osh.mathforkids/files/Pictures/cameraPicture.jpg
```

Any help is appreciated!

---

### **Update**

Following CommonsWare comment, I have changed the getOrientation method to use android.support.media.ExifInterface. Looks like it handles URIs from both gallery and camera (with FileProvider).

Is it a good solution? Will it detect orientation on all devices? What is the impact in terms of app memory usage?

```
public static int getOrientation(Context context, Uri selectedImage) {
    InputStream in = null;
    int rotation = 0;
    try {
        in = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
        ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(in);
        // Now you can extract any Exif tag you want
        // Assuming the image is a JPEG or supported raw format
        int orientation = exifInterface.getAttributeInt(
                ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
        switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                rotation = 90;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                rotation = 180;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                rotation = 270;
                break;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Handle any errors
        return rotation;
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException ignored) {}
        }
    }
    return rotation;
}
```

---

Comment: `MediaStore` does not know anything about images from your `FileProvider`. [Use `ExifInterface`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/media/ExifInterface) to determine the orientation.

Comment: Thanks. I've just edited my question to indicate that when I generate the uri from the file path, I get null cursor. And this is not related to file provider, correct me if I'm wrong. As for using the cursor instead of  ExifInterface, I've read that it's more efficient since I don't have to load the image just for getting the orientation.

Comment: "when I generate the uri from the file path, I get null cursor" -- no, your question has "I get an error on camera picture when calling "cursor.getInt(0)"". Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash. If you do not understand the stack trace, edit your question and post that stack trace. "I've read that it's more efficient" -- as I wrote, `MediaStore` does not know anything about images from your `FileProvider`. It cannot be more efficient if it does not work.

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my question according to your advice to use ExifInterface with a new implementation of getOrientation method. I would appreciate your opinion about it.

Comment: "Looks like it handles URIs from both gallery and camera (with FileProvider)" -- it would be more efficient for you to just use the `File`, when you have it (your `FileProvider` scenario). "Will it detect orientation on all devices?" -- there is no requirement for an image to have orientation data. "What is the impact in terms of app memory usage?" -- AFAIK, `ExifInterface` does not decode the whole image, but just reads in the EXIF tags, so it should be OK.

Comment: "it would be more efficient for you to just use the File" - getContentResolver().openInputStream() gets Uri as input. What should I use if I want to give it the File itself?

Comment: Use [the `ExifInterface` constructor that takes a string](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/media/ExifInterface.html#ExifInterface(java.lang.String)), passing in the path to the file (e.g., `getAbsolutePath()` on a `File` object). Or, create a `FileInputStream` on the `File`, and pass that to the constructor that you are using. Either way avoids the overhead of the `FileProvider`.